Undefine Storekit of xcode building
I got an error during building a project on Xcode
How can I pass this build or there is any solutions? I using Mac Intel.
I am looking for solution and apply but it still not working?
I try add the undefined Storekit at Link binary ... at Build phrase

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_$s8StoreKit11TransactionV5OfferV11PaymentModeV9freeTrialAGvgZ"
Undefined symbol:
_$s8StoreKit11TransactionV5OfferV11paymentModeAE07PaymentF0VSgvg
Undefined symbol: _$s8StoreKit11TransactionV5OfferV4typeAC0D4TypeVvg
Undefined symbol: _$s8StoreKit11TransactionV5OfferVMa
Undefined symbol: _$s8StoreKit11TransactionV5OfferVMn
Undefined symbol: _$s8StoreKit11TransactionV5offerAC5OfferVSgvg
Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)


Have you fixed above issue?

My issue is resolve after downgrading all firebase related packages.

That symbol is only available if you have Xcode 15.1+, upgrade your build environment to a more modern Xcode
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/transaction/offer/paymentmode/4307062-freetrial
